# CSS Table Layout

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table with 3 columns and amount of text in each column is variable. I would like to set some rules on the layout of the table but Im not sure how to do that in CSS.

```
Title   | Author | Publisher
```

The default ratio is 50%, 25%, 25% for each column. The goal is to keep everything on a single line if possible. The author and publisher columns have a higher priority to be single lined that the title column.

UPDATE: The problem is when the amount of text exceeds the width of a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the percentages to defined widths(px). Define the width of the table, as well as give each `<TD>` it's own width definition that together equal the width of the table. Best way would be to create a CSS class for both, and just assign the class to each element. Something like this, very general obviously.

```
.table{
  width:500px;
}

.tablecell_1{
  width:200px;
}

.tablecell_2{
  width:200px;
}

.tablecell_3{
  width:100px;
}

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="tablecell_1">
    </td>
    <td class="tablecell_2">
    </td>
    <td class="tablecell_3">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class for each of the columns.

```
<th class="title">Title</th>
<th class="author">Author</th>
<th class="publisher">Publisher</th>
```

And make css specific for each one.

```
.title{
}

.author{
}

.publisher{
}
```

Comment: I've done that already. It doesn't display the table the way I described when the text exceeds a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Define a width for the table and then add a class on `<td>` tags with `width:auto;

```
.table{
  width:900px;
}

.cell{
  width:auto;
}
```

And here your table

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">
    </td>
    <td class="cell">
    </td>
    <td class="cell">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Let me now if this is what you wish

Comment: your example is wrong, you have no CSS class defined for "cell"